# how to get form data value on server while upload file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, multer

I have a form in which i have `one user input field where user type his name and one type="file" which need to be uploaded on server` .I am able to upload file on server
but I want to fetch request parameter on server (`user enter name`) .I used `body-parser` to get value (req.body) , but getting `undefined`

**HTML**

```
<form id="fileUploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileId"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="submit">
    username <input type="text" placeholder="enter first name"  name="username" />
</form>
```

**JS client**

```
$('.submit').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($('#fileId').val().length === 0) {
                alert('please insert file')
            } else {
                var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

                // Create an FormData object
                var data = new FormData(form);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false, // Don't process the files
                    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (typeof data.error === 'undefined') {
                            // Success so call function to process the form
                        }
                        else {
                            // Handle errors here
                            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // Handle errors here
                        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

my file is uploaded successfully on server , but I am confused on these two lines

```
  var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
    // Create an FormData object
  var data = new FormData(form);
```

what is in data ? from my point of view data contain `username value and file data which need to be uploaded`

**server code**

how to fetch `username and file data` value on server .I already user bodypaser plugin , but req.body is undefined

here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// use of body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1])
    }
});
var upload = multer({ //multer settings
    storage: storage
}).single('file');


app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req)
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: err});
            return;
        }
        res.json({error_code: 0, err_desc: null});
    });
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening to ${PORT}`);
})
```

how to get form field values on server which is passed from client ?

Answer (score 0):

Add one more key in formdata.

```
var data = new FormData();
var files = $("#fileId").get(0).files;
data.append("fileUploadForm", files[0]);
data.append("Username",$('[name="username"]').val());
```

Use reference [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Comment: what are changes on server ?

Comment: I need i need change something on server also

Comment: your server code in node.js? you can google it "how to get form data in node.js key value"

Comment: yes in node js ..`var files = $("#fileUploadForm").get(0).files;` is giving `undefined`

Comment: set id property  "  <input type="file" id="inputfile" name="file" id="fileId"/>" and use $("#inputfile").get(0).files;